# Make Geneos to send HTTP GET request

Tags: rest, monitoring, geneos, itrs

I am using Geneos for monitoring, and want it to monitor a rest api endpoint of an app, so geneos should perform GET http request and take a response. Is there a way to do this?

As far as I know, there are rest api and rest extractor plugins, but they are only process inbound requests.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to use `toolkit` plugin and `curl` to check rest api endpoint.